# presence_of_element_located: 'str' object has no attribute 'w3c'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Selenium/Python: I am trying to use a WebDriverWait to locate an element by xpath. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, and the same basic thing is working in other parts of the code. I have been in the Java world for a while and am readjusting to python.

It raises an error:

> ```
> File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 964, in find_element
>    if self.w3c:  
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'w3c'
> ```

I have tried with an without extra parentheses in the argument to presence_of_element_located

The xpath has been changed to "//*" for illustration purposes but the error remains the same even when I use this xpath.

```
return WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout, 0.5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had quite a few issues using Expected Conditions and faced intermittent errors.

I called WebDriverWait in the following manner and it works in my environment/use-case.

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_xpath(element_xpath).is_displayed())
```

Hope this helps!